# Test graphs and solutions for MAXCUT

Tags: algorithm, dataset

I'm doing some work on [Max Cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut), and the algorithm I have works on every graph that I can think to throw at it, but those have been graphs that I can work out the solution by hand to validate, so they've been somewhat small. I am looking for a bunch of medium/large graphs (in any format, I dont mind writing parsers) that already have a solution found for Max Cut. I figure there has to be training data out there somewhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some randomly generated instances with solution sizes [here](https://biqmac.aau.at/biqmaclib.html).

Comment: Link looks dead.  Any other link someone?